# Problem reading sqlite table as csv file in recommender system

Tags: django, python-3.x, pandas, collaborative-filtering

I have to import a rating sqlite table as a csv file for my recommender system. The recommender.py looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from .models import movies,rating

movies=pd.read_csv('movies.csv')
ratings=pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')

 movies.head()
 ratings.head()

 def replace_name(x):
 return movies[movies['movie_id']==x].title.values[0]

 ratings.movie_id=ratings.movie_id.map(replace_name)

 userRatings=ratings.pivot_table(index=['account_id'], columns=
 ['movie_id'], values='rating')
  corrMatrix=userRatings.corr(method='pearson')

 myRatings=userRatings.loc[5].dropna()
 simCandidates=pd.Series()
 for i in range (0,len(myRatings.index)):
     sims=corrMatrix[myRatings,index[i]].dropna()
     sims=sims.map(lambda x: x*myRatings[i])
     simCandidates=simCandidates.append(sims)

 simCandidates.sort.values(inplace=True,ascending=False)
 simCandidates=simCandidates.groupby(simCandidates.index).sum()
 simCandidates=simCandidates.drop(myRatings.index)
```

I have a basic webapp in django that takes ratings of various movies from a user. After the user rates all the movies, the recommender system then recommends certain movies to the user. I am saving the ratings data in a **rating** model. However, I can't read a database table directly in my recommender.py as shown above as I need a csv file - 'rating.csv'. How can I directly import the rating table in my sqlite database as a csv file in the code posted above and what changes do I have to make in the above code?

Please help.

Comment: Your Sqlite file name is rating.csv or rating.sqlite?

Comment: i have a db file db.sqlite3 which contains a table 'rating'

Answer (score 1):

To read Sqlite in Pandas.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
# Create your connection.
db = sqlite3.connect('rating.db')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name", db)
```

In order to use read_sql_table(), you must have the SQLAlchemy optional dependency installed. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#reading-tables

Comment: sqlite3 is already in the standard library in python3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html, so should it work out of the box?

Comment: is there no way I can access the rating table as csv file?

Comment: @SparshKedia Is my approach that much hard? Just two line extra I think.

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi is your answer still valid for edited question above? Thank you for your help.